# SPF fails for emails sent from Azure App using Office 365 mail flow connector

Tags: asp.net, azure, smtp, spf

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web app hosted on Azure PaaS that sends emails using Office 365 subscription. Now the trouble is the emails that are failing SPF check.

In Azure portal, I get a public IP address (a.b.c.d) under Custom Domains that I've used in SPF record. SPF record is correct. But when users receive emails it has SPF fail on it and the IP address it comes from shows as something different (e.f.g.h). I checked the IP address, it's one of Microsoft Azure's.

This is my SPF record (a.b.c.d is the Azure provided public IP):

```
v=spf1 ip4:a.b.c.d include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

From Exchange Admin Center (office 365), I also have added a mailflow connector with a.b.c.d. It still fails SPF check. I think that a.b.c.d IP address that Microsoft has provided is for A record only and for SMTP client connection it use different IP address (like e.f.g.h, I didn't add that on SPF yet. Because I assume it's a dynamic IP address).

Can anyone help me on this, please? Thanks

Comment: If you're in a dynamic allocation block, you don't have much choice but to allow the whole block in your SPF. If you do a `whois` on your IP, you'll see the block it's within, and can add that to your record. Alternatively do a bit more searching - MS may provide an SPF for azure containing all their blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Synchro